# How to do reverse routing from subcontroller to the sub routes in play scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I have created the  sub routes from main route and I have created the subcontroller package e.g controllers.subcontrollers. Now how to access my sub routes from sub controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access by using this:

```
// Redirect to /hello/Bob
def helloBob = Action {
  Redirect(routes.Application.hello("Bob"))
}
```

As you can see in the playframework documentation.

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting

But, if you meant that you have multiples controllers and divided them into packages and want to access them inside another another controller. You can achieve it using something like this:

controllers.packageName.routes.ControllerName.functionInsideController

Comment: Its working fine.but one more question I have.How to reverse route the controllers.Example,where its route file is in subroute.routes .

Comment: @srini If I understood your question right, you define all the routes in the conf->routes file. You can define other way besides this, but the default you put all the routes in the same file independent it is from different packages. Example:  `GET     /route1                                 controllers.classControler1.definition

GET     /route2                                 controllers.classControler2.definition`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new route ex: **subcontrollers.routes**

```
main routes Ex:
-> /subcontrollers  subcontrollers.Routes

subcontrollers.routes Ex:
    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET    /assets/*file                            controllers.subcontrollers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

    GET    /example                           controllers.subcontrollers.SubController.sample(parameter1:Long,parameter2: String)
```

[Reference Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/1AFhy1zgBRk)